# SQL optimization options in Java

Tags: java, sql, orm, query-optimization

Let's say I have a basic query like:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM x WHERE y=[Z]
```

In this query, `[Z]` is a "variable" with different values injected into the query.

Now consider a situation where we want to do the same query with 2 known different values of `[Z]`, say `Z1` and `Z2`. We can make two separate queries:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM x WHERE y=Z1

SELECT a, b, c FROM x WHERE y=Z2
```

Or perhaps we can programmatically craft a different query like:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM x WHERE y in (Z1, Z2)
```

Now we only have one query (1 < 2), but the query construction and result set deconstruction becomes slightly more complicated, since we're no longer doing straightforward simple queries.

Questions:

- What is this kind of optimization called? (Is it worth doing?)
- How can it be implemented cleanly from a Java application?

  - Do existing Java ORM technologies help?

Answer (score 2):

> What is this kind of optimization called?

I'm not sure if there is a "proper" term for it, but I've heard it called query batching or just plain batching.

> (Is it worth doing?)

It depends on:

- whether it is worth the effort optimizing the query at all,
- the number of elements in the set; i.e. `... IN ( ... )`,
- the overheads of making a JDBC request versus the costs of query compilation, etc.

But in the right circumstances this is *definitely* a worthwhile optimization.

> How can it be implemented cleanly from a Java application?

It depends on your definition of "clean" :-)

> Do existing Java ORM technologies help?

It depends on the specific ORM technology you are talking, but (for example) the Hibernate HQL language supports the constructs that would allow you to do this kind of thing.

Comment: I was hoping that if the basic single query is a server-side prepared statement, then perhaps we can send the two queries at once, and knowing that the two queries are on the same prepared statement with different parameters, the server would do The Right Thing and optimize it better than if we try to do this in the Java layer. Am I mistaken in believing that such thing is not only possible, but also best practice?

Comment: A JDBC driver cannot combine two queries occurring one after another into one.  Each query is executed individually.  Besides, a JDBC driver typically does not parse the SQL; that happens in the database engine.

Answer (score 0):

An RDBMS can normally return the result of a query with IN **in equal or less time** than it takes to execute two queries.

If there is no index on column Y, then a full table scan is required. With two queries, two table scans will be performed instead of one.

If there is an index, then the single value in the WHERE clause, or the values in the IN list, are used one at a time to look up the index. When some rows are found for one of the values in the IN list, they are added to the returned result.

So it is better to use the IN predicate from the performance point of view.

When Y represents a column with unique values, then it is easy to decompose the result. Otherwise, there is slightly more work.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly can't say how much of a hit (if any) you will get if you run this two Prepared queries (even using [plain JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)) over combining them with an `IN` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array or List of values, you *could* manually build the prepare statement using JDBC:

```
// Assuming values is an int[] and conn is a java.sql.Connection
// Also uses Apache Commons StringUtils

StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT a, b, c FROM x WHERE y IN (");

query.append(StringUtils.join(Collections.nCopies(values.length, "?"), ',');
query.append(")");

PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query.toString());

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    stmt.setInt(i + 1, values[i]);
}

stmt.execute();
// Get results after this
```

Note: I haven't actually tested this.  In theory, if you used this a lot, you'd generalize this and make it a method.

Answer (score 0):

Note that an "in" (where blah in ( 1, 5, 10 ) ) is the same as writing "where blah = 1 OR blah = 5 OR blah = 10".  This is important if you are using, say, Apache Torque which would create lovely prepared statements *except* in the case of an "in" clause.  (That might be fixed by now.)

And the difference in performance that we found between the unprepared in clause and the prepared ORs was huge.

So a number of ORMs handle it, but not all of 'em handle it well.  Be sure to examine the queries sent to the database.

And while deconstructing the combined result set from a single query might be more difficult than handling a single result, it's probably a lot easier than trying to combine two result sets from two queries.  And probably significantly faster if a lot of duplicates are involved.